# How to get total rows with count?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to ask how to get total rows in table?

If I have a table like this:

[image: Img1]

it all works.

But what if I have table with 2 columns:

[image: Img2]

and the total will be 5

I just want to how to get total like my second image?

Thanks in advance

Comment: No one can see your images without clicking on an unverified link and is there a reason you cannot describe texturally your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My original answer, which I left below, shows you how to use grouping sets to obtain just the count for the entire table.  If you want your expected output verbatim, then the only option might a union query like this:

```
SELECT
    COALESCE(t.id, 'total') AS id,
    t.item
FROM
(
    SELECT CONVERT(varchar(10), id) AS id, item
    FROM cte
    UNION ALL
    SELECT null, CONVERT(varchar(10), COUNT(*))
    FROM cte
) t
ORDER BY CASE WHEN t.id IS NOT NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END;
```

This gave the following output in the [demo](http://rextester.com/IUUUOK39369):

[image]

You can also try using grouping sets if you only want the line containing the total:

```
SELECT
    id,
    COALESCE(item, 'total') AS item,
    COUNT(*) AS item_count
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY
    GROUPING SETS((id, item), ());
```

Grouping sets is probably a more powerful and flexible way to include this type of information than union queries.

**Output:**

[image]

**Demo here:**

## Rextester

Comment: thanks for help before.
but your answer its like my first table...
can i get total below item name and disappear item_count table?
because i dont need that field

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tablename

SELECT COUNT(columnname) FROM tablename
```

In the second query, write the column name you want to count from the table.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT COUNT (*) FROM TABLE_NAME
```

It will work for you